# Android widget with list view is refreshing items with ugly short "flashing" effect

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-widget, android-service

I would like to make a widget with a ListView, where you can add listItems to show counter timers to see how much time you have for an event.

This is the first time i use widgets i dont know if my approach is good or bad, so far i got this:

AppWidgetProvider for starting a runnable with periodic event that lauches a service. The service is called UpdateService which is updating the data set and refreshes the listView.

Well, i could say it is working, but each time the refreshing happens, my list view flashes for a short amount of time, it is like the list item is disappearing for a very short amount of time then re appears with refreshed values. It is pretty ugly i would like to have rid of it.

I tried to change cacheColorHint of the listView to #00000000 but didnt solved my problem and coudnt find anything on the internet either.

Please help if you can, and also give some advice if this aproach is not the best for achive this "time counter list"

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

static public String TAG = "widgetProvider";
static Handler handler = new Handler();
//TODO: stop runnables at widget destroying
static MyRunnable myRunnable;
static long refreshInterval = 1000 * 1;

//Runnable for refreshing my widget
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    Context context;

    public MyRunnable(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "My runnable has ran!");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, refreshInterval);
    }
}

//Service for updating the widget
public static class UpdateService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.i(TAG, "UpdateService - onStart()");
        int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), WidgetProvider.class));
        int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        Log.i(TAG, "appWidgetIds.length: " + appWidgetIds.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            //Changing dataset
            ListProvider.populateAndRefreshData();
            //Notifying the listview about the change
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.listViewWidget);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    //TODO: stop runnables
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    //init each widget, then call the runnable for periodic event for counting time
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
    }

    //start the runnable
    myRunnable = new MyRunnable(context);
    handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 0);
}


private static RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "updating a widget: " + appWidgetId);
    //which layout to show on widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    //setting a unique Uri to the intent
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    //setting adapter to listview of the widget
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
    //setting an empty view in case of no data
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);
    return remoteViews;
}
}
```

RemoteViewService is for defining the adapter

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

/*
 * Defining the Adapter of the listview here Adapter is ListProvider
 */
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
}
}
```

Adapter:

```
/**
 * Adapter of ListView
 * 
 */

public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

public static ArrayList<Record> listItemList = new ArrayList<Record>();
private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;

public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    populateAndRefreshData();
}
//TODO: just test populating
public static void populateAndRefreshData() {
    listItemList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    Record record = new Record();
    record.name = DateUtils.getIntervalToDate("2015-07-01 10:00:00");
    record.content = "...";
    record.icon = R.drawable.logo_1;
    listItemList.add(record);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemList.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
/*
 * Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of Viewwe return RemoteViews
 */
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
    Record listItem = listItemList.get(position);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.name);
    remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, listItem.icon);
    return remoteView;
}
@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {}
@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {}
}
```